# Why device->kobj->parent is equal to &device->parent->kobj as per LDD3?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I was going though chapter 14 of LDD3 and found following in the section 4;

> As a general rule, device->kobj->parent is equal to
>   &device->parent->kobj

Can someone please explain why so?

I read section 1,2,3. But I guess I missed something or couldn't digest it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think this as inheritance of the object oriented concept.

A struct kobject represents a kernel object, so device is kind subclass of a kobject.

```
struct device {
  struct device * parent;
  struct device_private * p;
  struct kobject kobj;
  ..
}    

struct kobject {
        char                    *k_name;
        char                    name[KOBJ_NAME_LEN];
        struct kref             kref;
        struct list_head        entry;
        struct kobject          *parent;
        struct kset             *kset;
        struct kobj_type        *ktype;
        struct dentry           *dentry;
};
```

A device has its parent device, and parent device's kobject is also parent of device's kobject. This relationship is taken care by the the linux kernel.

That's why device->kobj->parent equal to device->parent->kobj. (Device's kobject's parent equals to device's parent's kobject).